# Need to restart glassfish after each time sendmail function is used

Tags: java, netbeans7.0

I am facing a terrible problem with java Netbeans.

Each time I run my sendmail function used for registration successfully, which means that 
1. my database is successfully updated with the new user;
2. email is successfully sent to designated recipent,

I will need to restart my glassfish after each run before I could do another registration with the function of sendmail.

If I don't restart my glassfish and do another registration, everything goes fine with the database (updated with no issues), however the mail does not get sent at all.

So in short, my sendmail could only work once, and would require restarting glassfish before another sendmail can be done.

Any java/netbeans gurus can help? Greatly appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/javamail.html

Perhaps you can run in debugging mode and post your log entries. Need more information on what happens after your first email is sent.

Comment: hi, thanks for helping. i ran in debug mode, but im not sure where the log file is. Is it under glassfish tab?

Comment: http://sharp-developer.net/Fun/Bart-Question.aspx
http://thedata.org/book/check-glassfish-logs
Read first link then second link.

Comment: SEVERE: java.lang.SecurityException: Access to default session denied
 at javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(Session.java:320)
 at controllers.MailClient.processRequest(MailClient.java:51)
 at controllers.StaffController.saveUser(StaffController.java:99)

These are the first few errors received after the unsuccessful run